# Java (ZipEntry) - if the file name contains czech characters (čžř etc) it fails while reading next entry

Tags: java, inputstream, zip, zipinputstream

I have a problem when I try to unzip file contains files with special characters.

Lets say I have a zip file gallery.zip with image files.

```
gallery.zip
  - file01.jpg
  - dařbuján.jpg
```

My method starts:

```
public List<File> unzipToTemporaryFolder(ZipInputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    List<File> files = new LinkedList<File>();
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];

    while ((entry = inputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
```

It fails in inputStream.getNextEntry() when I try to read file **dařbuján.jpg** because of czech letters "ř" and "á". It works well with the other files for example with spaces (104 25.jpg or simply file.jpg etc.). Can you help me please?

Comment: And it fails... how exactly?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I've googled your problem. It's easy to find.

Comment: Really? I cannot find any working solution...

Comment: Then I presume you're not on Java 7. For earlier versions you are out of luck. Did you read [this](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4244499) bug report?

Comment: It is bad... I need compile by Java 6.

Comment: A few more explanation on bug 4244499 (mentionned by @MarkoTopolnik) : https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/non_utf_8_encoding_in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it with commons-compress. If somebody is interested here is my method:

```
public List<File> unzipToTemporaryFolder(ZipInputStream inputStream,
        File tempFile) throws IOException {
    List<File> files = new LinkedList<File>();
    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];

    org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile zf = new org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile(tempFile, "UTF-8");
    Enumeration<?> entires = zf.getEntries();
    while(entires.hasMoreElements()) {
        org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry entry = (org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry)entires.nextElement();
        if(entry.isDirectory()) {
            unzipDirectoryZipEntry(files, entry);
        } else {            
            InputStream zin = zf.getInputStream(entry);                 

            File temp = File.createTempFile(entry.getName().substring(0, entry.getName().length() - 4) + "-", "." + entry.getName().substring(entry.getName().length() - 3, entry.getName().length()));                                     

            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(temp), BUFFER);
            while ((count = zin.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            zin.close();
            outputStream.close();
            files.add(temp);            
        }
    }
    zf.close();
    return files;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your *ZipInputStream* with *Charset* specified using

```
 ZipInputStream(InputStream in, Charset charset)
```

like

```
new ZipInputStream(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Well there is a problem that ZipInputStream accepts only one parameter... InputStream in. No charset.

Comment: Oh I see. This is Java 7 thing.